# Search documents modified last two days

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-search

I am trying to search for all document that has been modified within last x numbers of days. I am using following query:

> LastModifiedTime>{Today-1}

However as you can see by image below this query does not work.

[image]

Comment: I think you need to create a view with greater than and less than condition with modified column filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a range of dates:  (write is an alias for LastModifiedTime)

```
write=2/1/2015..2/8/2015
```

You can use names of date ranges:

```
write="this week"
```

The supported ranges are:

- today
- yesterday
- this week
- last week  *(from Thomas Segato!)*
- this month
- last month
- this year
- last year

You can also use >, < etc.

Time Zone note: Search internally stores dates in Universal Time. Because of this, a file uploaded “2/7/2015 10:50 PM EST” will not be found by USA users with a search for “Write=2/7/2015” (or “LastUpdateDate=2/7/2015”). That file will be found with a search using “Write=2/8/2015”.

Comment: Very helpfull. Thanks!

Comment: Kind of funny I just tested last week which also works but not documented.